# Proving a given function has partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$ but it is not differentiable at that point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Consider the mapping $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by

$$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\displaystyle\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} & \textrm{se}& (x, y)\neq (0, 0)\\
(0, 0)& \textrm{se}& (x, y)=(0, 0)
\end{array}\right..$$

I would like to show $f$ has partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$ but $f$ is not differentiable at this point.

My attempt goes as follows:

For any $k\neq 0$ we have

$$\frac{f(0+k, 0)-f(0, 0)}{k}=\frac{f(k, 0)}{k}=\frac{k\cdot 0^2/(k^2+0^2)}{k}=\frac{0}{k}=0$$

whereas for every $l\neq 0$ we have:

$$\frac{f(0, 0+l)-f(0, 0)}{l}=\frac{f(0, l)}{l}=\frac{0\cdot l^2/(0^2+l^2)}{l}=\frac{0}{l}=0.$$

This shows that $$\partial_x f(0, 0)=\partial_y f(0, 0)=0.$$

Finally, notice that for every $t\neq 0$ we have:

$$\frac{f(0+t, 0+t)-f(0, 0)-0\cdot t-0\cdot t}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}}=\frac{f(t, t)}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}}=\frac{t\cdot t^2/(t^2+t^2)}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}}=\frac{t^3/2t^2}{\sqrt{2t^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{t}{|t|}.$$
Therefore, this quotient does not go to zero as $(t, t)\to (0, 0)$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. For the sake of context, you should specify the definition of differentiability you're using. Here, it seems to be $f'(x,y):=\lim\limits_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-\nabla f(x,y)\bullet (h,k)}{|(h,k)|}$

Comment: That is exactly the definition I'm using. Thanks =)